# Is parameter binding sequenced after argument evaluation?

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, evaluation, c++11, move-semantics

Suppose I have the following function:

```
void foo(std::vector<int> vec, int n);
```

If I call the function like this:

```
std::vector<int> numbers { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19 };
foo(std::move(numbers), numbers[0]);
```

Are all the arguments completely evaluated before being bound to their parameters? In that case, the `std::move` is harmless, because it simply yields an xvalue referring to `numbers`. Or can each individual argument immediately be bound to its parameter as soon as it is evaluated? In that case, `numbers[0]` could cause undefined behavior, because `numbers` could already have been moved into `vec`.

Comment: `numbers[0]` will not throw, right? You mean `numbers.at(0)`, right?

Comment: In debug mode, `numbers[0]` can do all the sanity checks it wants to.

Comment: @R. Martinho: I took the liberty of editing the question. I don't think "cause an exception" is the important part of the question, but rather whether the object can be moved before all arguments are evaluated.

Comment: @FredOverflow: That is undefined behavior, and it can cause any effect in any mode (debug/release). A conforming implementation might decide to *throw* an exception, or *assert* or any other behavior.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On §1.9/15 we're told that:

> When calling a function (whether or not the function is inline), every value computation and side effect
>   associated with any argument expression, or with the postfix expression designating the called function, is
>   sequenced before execution of every expression or statement in the body of the called function. (...)

And on §5.2.2/4:

> (...) The initialization and destruction of each parameter occurs within the context of the
>   calling function. (...)

I couldn't find any other relevant text in the final draft. Since this does not explicitly define a *sequenced before* relationship between evaluation of arguments and the initialization of the parameters, they're *unsequenced* and the `std::move` is not harmless.

A solution to this issue would be to force a sequence with a temporary variable:

```
std::vector<int> numbers { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19 };
int num = numbers[0];
foo(std::move(numbers), num);
```